# How to restrict editing to the user who created with Grails

Tags: grails, spring-security

Any user can create his/her own robot. A robot should be edited only by the creator or an administrator.

The **next code works perfectly** and it is an **easy and simple solution**:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils

class RobotController {

    def springSecurityService

    def edit() {

        if (Robot.get(params.id).usuario.username == springSecurityService.authentication.name
         || SpringSecurityUtils.ifAnyGranted("ROL_ADMIN,ROL_SUPERADMIN"))               
            println "editing allowed"
        else
            println "editing denied"

    }
}
```

But my teacher recommended me to secure the web **using Config.groovy**. The next code does **not work**:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    '/index.gsp': ["isAuthenticated()"],
    '/robot/edit/**': ["Robot.get(params.id).usuario.username == springSecurityService.authentication.name
                        || hasAnyRole('ROL_ADMIN','ROL_SUPERADMIN')"],
    '/robot/**': ["isAuthenticated()"]
]
```

It does not work because different reasons:

1. It is not possible to call the domain class `Robot` in Config.groovy
2. `params.id` has no sense in this place
3. The Java "or" (`||`) is not valid here. I tried other ways with not luck. The [Groovy documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators) is not clear for me.

Is possible to do it in Config.groovy? If not, the correct way would be using [`<sec:access> ... </sec:access>`](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/6%20Helper%20Classes.html#6.1%20SecurityTagLib) somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do that kind of thing with plain Spring Security core.

Your teacher is right in the sense that you probably shouldn't implement the security in an ad-hoc manner, but you don't necessarily should do it in the Config.groovy -- that is a bit limiting.

You probably want to use the [Spring Security ACL plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-acl), it adds some more domain classes and allows you to set up the access control with much more fine grained detail.

Check out [the official docs](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-acl/docs/manual/). It may take a little while for you to learn it, but it is much better than rolling out your own ACL mechanism.

Comment: Thank you. I have been reading the documentation carefully. It looks a nice plugin, but I think it increases the complexity of the code innecesarely. In this case, I prefer the code I posted (`if (Robot.get(params.id).usuario.username ==`...) as it is simple and works. I'm going to keep the answer open a couple of days to see if somebody could give us any other idea. If not, I'll accept this answer as it is perfectly correct. Though I would use this plugin for more complex cases.